# Twitter Application Only Auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, rest-client

I'm trying to get an Application Only Auth token following the steps of this link: 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth

I'm using Ruby on Rails and Rest Client to make the POST request needed and I'm setting the headers (I think) properly.

The step-by-step says:

> URL encode the consumer key and the consumer secret according to RFC
>   1738. Note that at the time of writing, this will not actually change the consumer key and secret, but this step should still be performed
>   in case the format of those values changes in the future.
>
> Concatenate the encoded consumer key, a colon character ":", and the
>   encoded consumer secret into a single string.
>
> Base64 encode the string from the previous step.

And my code is:

```
require 'rest_client'

    key = URI::encode('app_key')
    secret = URI::encode('app_secret')
    encoded = Base64.encode64("#{key}:#{secret}")

    res = RestClient::Resource.new "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token/"
    response = ''

    options = {}
    options['Authorization'] = "Basic #{encoded}"
    options['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'

    res.post('grant_type=client_credentials', options) do |response, request, result|
        response << "#{CGI::escapeHTML(response.inspect)}<br /><br />"
        response << "#{CGI::escapeHTML(request.inspect)}<br /><br />"
        response << "#{CGI::escapeHTML(result.inspect)}<br />"
    end

    render :text => txt
```

And I print out this:

```
"{\"errors\":[{\"label\":\"authenticity_token_error\",\"code\":99,\"message\":\"Unable to verify your credentials\"}]}"

#<RestClient::Request:0x9ece5d8 @method=:post, @headers={"Authorization"=>"Basic bXlfa2V5Om15X3NlY3JldA==\n", "Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"}, @url="https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token/", @cookies={}, @payload="", @user=nil, @password=nil, @timeout=nil, @open_timeout=nil, @block_response=nil, @raw_response=false, @verify_ssl=false, @ssl_client_cert=nil, @ssl_client_key=nil, @ssl_ca_file=nil, @tf=nil, @max_redirects=10, @processed_headers={"Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/xml", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "Authorization"=>"Basic bXlfa2V5Om15X3NlY3JldA==\n", "Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", "Content-Length"=>"29"}, @args={:method=>:post, :url=>"https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token/", :payload=>"grant_type=client_credentials", :headers=>{"Authorization"=>"Basic bXlfa2V5Om15X3NlY3JldA==\n", "Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"}}>

#<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>
```

My key and secret are valid.
Am I missing something?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

Updating with the solution I've found.

The problem was on the Base64 convertion and string encoding.

I had to add a forced encoding parameter to the key+secret combination, for UTF-8 convertion:

```
encoded = Base64.encode64("#{key}:#{secret}".force_encoding('UTF-8'))
```

The Rails Base64.encode64 inserts a line break every 60 encoded characters.

The workaround was:

For Ruby 1.9+ (strict_ was included in Ruby 1.9)

```
Base64.strict_encode64(string)
```

For Ruby 1.9-

```
Base64.encode64(string).gsub('/\n/') # To remove the line break
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you trying to implement Authorization with Tweeter (as OAuth Provider). Instead of writing it from the scratch following the API documentation, I would suggest to use OmniAuth. The setup & boilerplate code is fairly easy to use.

Read more about it at http://www.omniauth.org/ & https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki

Let us know, if that helped you or not.

Comment: Thanks for the help Som Poddar, but I followed the "hard way" with the intention to fully understand the API's behavior. I will update with the solution I've found.