# Generating the application-only authentication for Twitter sdk with retrofit

Tags: android, twitter, oauth-2.0, retrofit2, twitter-fabric

Following the guide set out [here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only), I was able to generate the base64 token

```
try {
    byte[] byteArray = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s:%s", key, secret)
            .getBytes("UTF-8");
    String token = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    // Here is where I make the oauth request

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The next part to this is to make the api call and get the application specific token (using `Retrofit` if possible). This is currently what I have:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1")
private void obtainAccessToken() {
    final String BASE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token/";

}
```

How do I include the other parts and eventually make the request and obtain the token? An example of this in action is seen by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155389/twitter-application-only-auth), however this is in ruby. How do I achieve the same using Retrofit framework?